# Назначить событие click всем элементам селектора

Tags: jquery

Вообще не врубаюсь.

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $("#show_comments").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div').next().toggle();
  });
});
```

Работает только на первом элементе с id "show_comments". Что не так?

Comment: Уникальный идентификатор `id` может быть только один, на-то он и "уникальный".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

==только на первом элементе с id "show_comments"==
наверное потому что это ИД

> ИД -  уникальное имя элемента, которое используется для изменения его
>   стиля и обращения к нему через скрипты. Идентификатор в коде документа
>   должен быть в единственном экземпляре, иными словами, встречаться
>   только один раз.

используйте вместо ИД класс и будет всё нормально.

```
$(".show_comments").click(....
```

Answer (score 0):

.closest() .next() тут вобше не нужны и делают совсем другие функции!!

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
        $("#show_comments").click(function() {
            $('div').toggle();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias optio perferendis reiciendis.</p>
</div>


<button id="show_comments">Show / hide</button>
```

Comment: У меня немного другая структура и я не нашел другого способа добраться до нужного элемента. Там несколько div

Comment: тогда пишите весь код что не было путаницы

Comment: Я упустил лишние детали. Вы обратили внимание не на то, что нужно. Вопрос решен, спасибо

Comment: closest и next там как раз на своём месте стоят, это же сворачиваемые блоки